# Automapper throwing System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException: Ambiguous match found

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, exception, reflection, automapper

I have a piece of code that throws exception and I dont quite understand why.

```
 public  async Task<List<CategoryVm>> Handle(GetCategoriesListQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var categories = (await _categoryRepository.ListAllAsync()).OrderBy(x => x.Name);
      //  var list = categories.ToList();
        return _mapper.Map<List<CategoryVm>>(categories);
    }
```

[image]

I managed to get around problem as below. Would be be nice know why this works.

```
  public  async Task<List<CategoryVm>> Handle(GetCategoriesListQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var categories = (await _categoryRepository.ListAllAsync()).OrderBy(x => x.Name);
        var list = categories.ToList();
        return _mapper.Map<List<CategoryVm>>(list);
    }
```

Category and CategoryVm

```
public class CategoryVm
{
    public Guid CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } 
}
public class Category: AuditableEntity
{
    public Guid CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Event> Events { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: var categories = (await _categoryRepository.ListAllAsync()).OrderBy(x => x.Name) - this code will return IQueryable and calling ToList() will make the query to your db entity and the mapper can't map IQueryable to your CategoryVm.

Comment: @AchoVasilev AFAIK if mapper can't map something it throws an error that mapping was not set up. Also we don't know what is returned by `_categoryRepository.ListAllAsync()` -  it can be "ordinary" enumerable.

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/3817#issuecomment-1006047351

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu, thank you. It looks like there is a bug. I will try with a previous version of Automapper  as suggested in the post.

Answer (score 14):

In my case, the cause was using `.OrderBy()` method with Automapper 11.0.0 before mapping. My workaround was to use ordering afterwards.
This problem was fixed in 11.0.1 and after

Comment: Thanks, when I switched my Automapper version from 11.0.0 down to 10.1.0, it worked fine. Didnt expect that really.

Comment: Can also .ToList() the IEnumerable that is ordered.

Comment: I would better use new 11.0.1 version where this problem got fix

Comment: Seems to work again with v12

Answer (score 3):

In AutoMapper version 11.0.1 (now available) this bug is solved: calling IMapper.Map after an OrderBy caused an AmbiguousMatchException in version 11.0.0.

(A [link to this GitHub issue](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/3817) was shared by @Lucian Bargaoanu in a comment already, while the issue was in progress. Thanks for sharing!)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to add a `.ToList()` prior to calling ``.Map''
I'm using Automapper 11.0.0

Comment: Or you can simply upgrade :)

Comment: Our internal package sources haven't been updated yet so was left with this as my solution

Answer (score 0):

For all that have a hard time to debug this. Watch your property names. Automapper is using Reflection and internally this might cause issues with casing. I can easily trigger the error matching "BirthDay" and "Birthday" in the same class (D versus d). That's especially tricky if one uses this technique for backup fields and make both public (accidentally or on purpose) and add a getter.

Comment: Obviously don't do that :) But you must be using an older version, I see no such thing with the latest.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the reason was the use of the type of data Enum `GeoTypeClient`. To solve this problem, it was worth doing this:

```
CreateMap <getItemsRequest, GetItemsApiRequest>()
.ForMember(dto=> dto.Location, opt=> opt.MapFrom (q => (int)q.Location));
```

where the location has the `GeoTypeClient` data type represented as an Enum.